# How can I read lines from a live file?

Tags: c#

I've got 2 apps, one writes lines to a file, the other reads as the file is written.
The issue comes from regarding the file as a queue and not as a stream.
the writing is per line. reading with StreamReader::ReadLine.
The issue is that i'm getting only part of the line, so parsing fails.
What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: i'd say don't use a file to communicate between two apps; that's like sending an international parcel to someone sitting in the next room. connect them via a socket instead, for example.

Comment: Use [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication)

Comment: The issue: when you writing file, call `FileStream.Flush()` after writing of the each line. Because `FileStream` has an internal buffer that you may force to write to the file.

Comment: Yeah... File IO is pretty much the slowest thing you can do on your computer. There are so many better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Framework offers a [PipeStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipestream) and derived classes for inter-process communication on a local machine as a client-server using a stream in memory, not a file as in Unix as can be done using semaphores and queued pipes.

If you need one process populating a file, you can do that it send new data after written in the file to the other process using such stream pipe.

For example, in the server process:

```
void ProcessNewData(string /* or any type needed */ content)
{
  WriteNewDataToFile(content);
  SendNewDataToClient(content);
}
```

Here is an article that explain things in addition to the Microsoft documentation:

[Full Duplex Asynchronous Read/Write with Named Pipes (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1179195/Full-Duplex-Asynchronous-Read-Write-with-Named-Pip)

You can also use any inter-process technology you want : Remoting, WCF...

[Inter Process Communication (C# Vault)](https://csharpvault.com/inter-process-communication/)